# Google Places AutocompleteService filtering by country

Tags: google-places-api

I'm setting up a custom autocomplete field where I show locations from Google Places and events from my database that match the search query. For this reason, I'm using the Google Places Autocomplete Service to get the query predictions rather than plugging in the Places Autocomplete directly into my textfield.

The problem is I can't figure out how to filter Places Autocomplete suggestions by country using the AutoComplete service.

I've tried:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService(null, {
        types: ['cities'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: "au"}
    });
```

but it still shows autocomplete options from Germany and France:(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to pass the restrictions when you call the service, not when you create it. Here:

```
//create service
service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

//perform request. limit results to Australia
var request = {
    input: 'Brisbane',
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'},
};
service.getPlacePredictions(request, callback);
```

Comment: Hello Robert, how and where did you define your `callback`?

Comment: @chaeschuechli Have a look at the [official example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction). The function `displaySuggestions` is the callback.

Comment: @Apoorv It might be useful to note that service.getPlacePredictions works when passing the request.componentRestrictions, however the service.getQueryPredictions does not seem to

Comment: can you add restrictions to cities? for example `componentRestrictions: { city: 'nyc'}`?

Comment: `.AutocompleteService()` does not have `strictBounds` parameter. I was wondering if there is a parameter to limit results based on strict bounds.

Comment: @RobertDodd You can initialize the object adding the options. If you need to change the options, there is a function named `setOptions()` (see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)) which you can use to perform this action.

Comment: how to retrieve long and lat from callback result?

Answer (score 8):

You can specify types, and componentRestrictions using [AutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompletionRequest). Here is an example -

```
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

    service.getPlacePredictions({ input: query, types: ['geocode'], 
                                componentRestrictions:{ country: 'us' } },
            function (predictions, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    var results = document.getElementById('results');
                    for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
                        results.innerHTML += '<li>' + prediction.description + '</li>';
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in the documentation [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteService), the Places Library `AutocompleteService` does not support [AutocompleteOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions). If you think that this would be a valuable feature, please file a [Places API - Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: Can you be more specific about where that is outlined in the docs? From what I see, you can restrict by country.

Comment: Yes, I also just checked "componentRestrictions"

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array also for country restriction

```
const autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({
  input: '123',
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: ['us', 'ca'],
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this code.

```
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: ["in"]}
}
//Find From location    
var input= document.getElementById('input_box_city');
var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: This is for the Autocomplete class, not the AutocompleteService class. The AutocompleteService class allows you to programatically deal with the results whereas the Autocomplete class decorates an input element for you.

Answer (score -1):

Use this working Code

```
var input = document.getElementById("query_value");
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
  componentRestrictions: { country: "IN" },
  place_id: "YOUR_PLACE_ID"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
});


https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en&key=YOUR_KEY
```